# How get "cidrblock" of a subnet in the "outputs" of a AWS Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a AWS Code formation. I have to print the Cidrblock of a subnet. But that does not work. Please help

```
"Resources": {
    "Subnet": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
              "Ref": "VPC"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
          }
    },
    Outputs : {
      "SubnetCIDR": {
          "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "Subnet",
              "CidrBlock"
            ]
          },
          "Description": "The CIDR"
        },
    }
```

This does not work. The following error message is shown while uploading the template:

> Template validation error: Template error: resource Subnet does not
>   support attribute type CidrBlock in Fn::GetAtt

Comment: can u define what is doesnot work mean?

Comment: I have added the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not supported.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html

If you look at the doc, the only supported attribute is **AvailabilityZone**

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem to be hard coding the CIDR block anyway, you could set it as a parameter and then just reference the parameter in both places.

```
"Parameters" : {
  "CidrBlock" : {
    "Type" : "String",
    "Default" : "10.0.0.0/16"
  }
},
"Resources" : {
  "Subnet" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties" : {
      "VpcId" : {
        "Ref" : "VPC"
      },
      "CidrBlock" : { "Ref" : "CidrBlock" }
    }
  }
},
"Outputs" : {
  "SubnetCIDR" : {
    "Value" : { "Ref" : "CidrBlock" },
    "Description": "The CIDR"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you not hard code the CidrBlock?
If I don't hard code the CidrBlock, I get this error: `Property CidrBlock cannot be empty.`.
And if I hard code it to `10.0.0.0/16`, I get this error: `The CIDR '10.0.0.0/16' is invalid. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Range;....`