# Cloudformation SubnetList get CidrBlock

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, vpc, infrastructure-as-code

I'm working on a new infrastructure provisioned with CloudFormation. I need to fetch a subnet cidrblock for the security groups.

I've tried some method for fetch the subnet Cidr blocks but I'm getting the following error:

```
YAML not well-formed
```

My template is:

```
 SubnetList:
    Description: 'Gateway Subnet Id'
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>

.....
..
....

ElastiCacheSecurityGroupIngressGateway: ##SubnetLists
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Properties:
    GroupId: !GetAtt SecGroup.GroupId
    IpProtocol: tcp
    FromPort: '6379'
    ToPort: '6379'
    CidrIp: Fn::GetAtt: [ Fn::Select: [ 0, !Ref SubnetList ], CidrBlock ]
```

I need the fetch cidr block from SubnetList.

How I can handle this?

Comment: Firstly, please always ensure that you include the _exact_ error message you see. Otherwise, when people google for that error message, your question in the archives won't be found. Secondly, because you have a YAML not well-formed message, no one can assist unless you provide the entire template, whereas you have only provided a snippet of it.

Comment: yaml well formed error is exact error message, i just want to learn how i can fetch the cidr block from subnet  added as a parameter . thanks for your advice

Comment: The error message would be "YAML not well-formed" see this page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-template-validation/).

Comment: it's my typo sorry, thanks :)

Comment: Best thing to do is copy/paste the exact error message in future. That's what I do. Also, it looks like you're trying to take the first SubnetId and put that in the CidrIp field. But that needs to be an IP address?

Comment: in my case i need the fetch cidr block of subnet because these subnet list is member of autoscaling and loadbalancer .

Comment: maybe it can be single subnet not a list , but which method provide fetching cidr block of subnet via subnetId in CloudFormation ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391999/3787051) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this unless you created the subnets within this same template. When using GetAtt you need to supply the name of a resource *within* the CloudFormation template. You're simply providing a parameter list of subnet IDs - those are strings, not CloudFormation-managed resources.

You could simply pass in the subnet CIDRs as parameters or, better still, reference them as outputs from the stack that created the VPC and subnets in the first place using [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html).

Also see [this proposed solution](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudformation-get-att-from-param/blob/master/GetAttFromParam.yaml) to the very same problem. Caveat: it's not trivial.